# Random Hex colour from an array

Tags: javascript, css, random, hex

I have the following code and am trying to simply make each item in an isotope grid have a different Hex value background colour. This code works to an extent but gives each item in the isotope the same colour, rather than a random one. Any help greatly appreciated, I'm no JS expert and have hacked the following from various sources to get to the current state.

If anybody has a more elegant solution as an alternative to a fix, I'm all ears!

Cheers

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var colors = ["#E1A2AC","#FDC300","#56AF31", "#39B6AB"];                
  var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length);           
  $('.colour-array').css("background-color", colors[rand]);
});
```

HTML

```
<article class="<?php echo $termsString; ?> isotope-brick">

    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
    <div id="brick-overlay" class="colour-array">
            <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
            <h5><?php the_excerpt(); ?></h5>
            <h4><?php $category = get_the_category(); echo $category[0]->cat_name;?></h4>
    </div><!-- end brick-overlay -->
    </a>

    <div id="brick-info">
            <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
            <h4 class="colour-array"><?php $category = get_the_category(); echo $category[0]->cat_name;?></h4>
    </div><!-- end brick-info -->

        <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { 
                  the_post_thumbnail();
            } ?>
</article>
```

Comment: You should iterate over the list of `.colour-array` selecting random color for each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve goals you described in comments and taking into consideration HTML structure you posted, I'd go the other way.

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  colorsCount = 4;
  var colorArray = $('.isotope-brick');
  $.each(colorArray, function (ind, obj) {
    $(obj).addClass('color' + Math.floor(Math.random() * colorsCount));
  });
});
```

and CSS (two entries for each color are necessary, but it gives elasticity when slightly different shade is needed, so no problem :-)

```
.isotope-brick.color0 .brick-overlay {
    background-color:#E1A2AC;
}

.isotope-brick.color0 .brick-info {
    color:#E1A2AC;
}
```

Working example here [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/crjghtqh/4/).

One tiny remark: I changed `brick-overlay` and `brick-info` ids into CSS classes, 'cause i think you are going to have more than one article on the site. I strongly recommend you doing the same. Here's [the why](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/127178/two-html-elements-with-same-id-attribute-how-bad-is-it-really).

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help, this is the perfect solution! Have a great weekend.

Answer (score 1):

Because your code executed once for the random array.
You need to put it in the loop.

Answer (score 1):

I'd rather try something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var colors = ["#E1A2AC","#FDC300","#56AF31", "#39B6AB"];
  $.each($('.colour-array'),function(ind,obj){
    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length);
    $(obj).css("background-color",colors[rand]);
  });
});
```

Check the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/crjghtqh/).

Comment: Sorry, there was some syntax error with braces and parentheses. I've just fixed that.

Answer (score 1):

I just realized how awesome jQuery can be from time to time. You can supply a 'value provider' function to `css` function ([docs](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css-propertyName-function)). Check this one:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var colors = ["#E1A2AC","#FDC300","#56AF31", "#39B6AB"];
  $('.colour-array').css("background-color",function(){
    return colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length)];
  });
});
```

Updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/crjghtqh/1/).

<strike>Edit:
Regarding your last comment, a possible solution I've come up to, yet pretty ugly is to copy one property's value into another. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/crjghtqh/2/).</strike>
 I don't like solution here proposed, because it depends on the order in which jQuery's `css` processes properties in given map. Better use next one.

**Edit:**
I've got a better idea though it would require some refactoring - calculate colors for each object first, then assign for all. Here comes [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/crjghtqh/3/) and code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var colors = ["#E1A2AC","#FDC300","#56AF31", "#39B6AB"];
    var colorMap = {};
    var colorArray = $('.colour-array');
    $.each(colorArray ,function(ind,obj){
        colorMap[ind] = colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length)];
    });
    var colorProvider = function(ind){
        return colorMap[ind];
    };
    colorArray.css({
        "background-color":colorProvider,
        "color":colorProvider
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I knew it must be possible, with a bit of expertise.

Comment: Hello again, further to this, would it be possible to achieve the following?

I would like to affect 2 css properties (background-color & color) in the same instance. I can duplicate part of the code to get this to work, but it will generate 2 different colours, rather than the same colour for the 2 css properties. In essence, I need these to be linked per item?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the update! It doesn't however force the two instances of .colour-array in the html to be in sync, they still load different colours? Also, as we are applying this to both 'background-color' and 'color', the text is not visible as it is the same colour font as the background. I realise this is a bit of a contradiction as it is obviously an issue related to calling the class twice (i.e running the script twice). 

I have edited my HTML above to show you my setup.

Comment: I don't get what 'in sync' means, but two `.colour-array` instance still **may** load same color. It is *random*. Two randoms in the same finite domain may outcome the same value with non-zero probability. If you wanted to randomly choose a color, but different each time, you'd need a different algorithm.

Comment: Hi Krzysztof. No I don't want a random colour generated, only one of the 4 hex values in the array. I would however like the 2 instances of '.colour-array' in the html (<h4> and <div id='brick-overlay'> to generate the same colour at the same time. Does that make sense? Perhaps this is not possible when calling the 'colour-array' class multiple times? Thanks.

Comment: Maybe instead it would be easier to shuffle the colors table, but have `.colour-array` colors from predefined position. If you're determined to randomly choose a color but have pairs, or tuples to always get same one... You'd need another algorithm. Where are those tuples defined? Do they change: Ever? Between executions? During the execution?

Comment: OK, So within the html I have 2 defined '.colour-array' classes, one of which needs the 'background-color' css and the other needs 'color'. These 2 instances need to pair up in terms of colour, but the specific colour is random from the array. At the moment they are not pairing up, and the fact that the random colour applies to both 'background-color' and 'color' means that the text is the same colour as the background. When the 'color' css is applied I wouldn't want 'background-color' also applied. They are not defined as pairs in the html, which is perhaps an issue?

Comment: The colours will change on refresh, so long as they remain 'paired'. Can you offer any modifications to the existing css/js/html? Thanks.

Comment: In such case, I'd define four classes, one for each color, then in javascript only assign one of those random classes for each **isotope-brick**. In separate css you then can define colors. Both shorter and cleaner.

Comment: Could you by any chance help me out on the JS side of things? As this is where I fall down! It would be greatly appreciated, and this sounds like a solid plan to achieve my aims. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Krzysztof, as an expanison to this I've opened a new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26888671/random-hex-colour

If you have any insight on this it would be much appreciated, almost there!