# Random hex colour

Tags: jquery, css, random

I am using the following code to generate a random hex colour on certain elements on my page.

CSS

```
/**** Random hex values ****/

.isotope-brick.color0 .brick-overlay {
background-color: #E1A2AC;
}

.isotope-brick.color0 .brick-info {
color: #E1A2AC;
}

.isotope-brick.color1 .brick-overlay {
    background-color: #FDC300;
}

.isotope-brick.color1 .brick-info {
    color: #FDC300;
}

.isotope-brick.color2 .brick-overlay {
    background-color: #56AF31;
}

.isotope-brick.color2 .brick-info {
    color: #56AF31;
}

.isotope-brick.color3 .brick-overlay {
    background-color: #39B6AB;
}

.isotope-brick.color3 .brick-info {
    color: #39B6AB;
}
```

JS

```
// Random hex colour
$(document).ready(function () {
    colorsCount = 4;
    var colorArray = $('.isotope-brick, .rsGCaption');
    $.each(colorArray, function (ind, obj) {
        $(obj).addClass('color' + Math.floor(Math.random() * colorsCount));
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<figure class="<?php echo get_post_type( $post ) ?> <?php echo $termsString; ?> isotope-brick">

        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
        <figcaption class="brick-overlay colour-array">
                <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                <h5><?php the_excerpt(); ?></h5>
                <h4><?php $category = get_the_category(); echo $category[0]->cat_name;?></h4>
        </figcaption><!-- end brick-overlay -->

        <figcaption class="brick-info">
                <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                <h4 class="colour-array"><?php $category = get_the_category(); echo $category[0]->cat_name;?></h4>
        </figcaption><!-- end brick-info -->

            <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { 
                      the_post_thumbnail();
                } ?>
        </a>
    </figure><!-- end figure -->
```

This all works great, but I want to extend it to another area of the site. I have a caption box styled in the same way inside the Royalslider plugin, and I would like to extend this random colour to the top margin and colour selectors. The site is citizenfilms.co.uk/beta. Any help here would be most appreciated!

Comment: Could you be more specific as to what your question is here?

Comment: I have another area on the site (outside of .isotope-brick) that I would like to apply the .colour-array class to. Although I don't seem to be able to get this to work?

Comment: Where on your site is this Royalslider?

Comment: On the homepage (citizenfilms.co.uk/beta), it is the large slider at the top of the page. The caption box is within this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Casey Rule for the advice re: positioning my custom JS code BELOW that of the plugin JS. That is the key here.

Once this is done it's simply a case of replacing the original css with the following.

Cheers Casey!

```
/**** Random hex values ****/

.isotope-brick.color0 .brick-overlay {
    background-color: #E1A2AC;
}

.isotope-brick.color0 .brick-info {
    color: #E1A2AC;
}

.rsGCaption.color0 {
    border-color: #E1A2AC;
    color: #E1A2AC;
}

.isotope-brick.color1 .brick-overlay {
    background-color: #FDC300;
}

.isotope-brick.color1 .brick-info {
    color: #FDC300;
}

.rsGCaption.color1 {
    border-color: #FDC300;
    color: #FDC300;
}

.isotope-brick.color2 .brick-overlay {
    background-color: #56AF31;
}

.isotope-brick.color2 .brick-info {
    color: #56AF31;
}

.rsGCaption.color2 {
    border-color: #56AF31;
    color: #56AF31;
}

.isotope-brick.color3 .brick-overlay {
    background-color: #39B6AB;
}

.isotope-brick.color3 .brick-info {
    color: #39B6AB;
}

.rsGCaption.color3 {
    border-color: #39B6AB;
    color: #39B6AB;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That caption box on your site, the one that uses the class `.rsGCaption`, is not in the DOM when the page first loads.  It is added to the DOM by this javascript at the bottom of the page:

```
<script id="new-royalslider-init-code" type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.new-royalslider-1').royalSlider({template:'default',image_generation:{lazyLoading:!0,imageWidth:'',imageHeight:'',thumbImageWidth:'',thumbImageHeight:''},thumbs:{thumbWidth:96,thumbHeight:72},autoPlay:{enabled:!0},width:'100%',height:'500px',autoScaleSliderWidth:960,autoScaleSliderHeight:750,slidesSpacing:0,imageScaleMode:'fill',imageScalePadding:0,arrowsNav:!1,globalCaption:!0,loopRewind:!0,keyboardNavEnabled:!0});
});
</script>
```

Your code to color the caption is happening as soon as the document is loaded, BEFORE the royalslider code has a chance to finish executing, and, therefore, before the slider caption is part of the DOM.  You just need to rearrange the code so that the royalSlider code executes before the caption coloring code.  Here is one option:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $('.new-royalslider-1').royalSlider({template:'default',image_generation:{lazyLoading:!0,imageWidth:'',imageHeight:'',thumbImageWidth:'',thumbImageHeight:''},thumbs:{thumbWidth:96,thumbHeight:72},autoPlay:{enabled:!0},width:'100%',height:'500px',autoScaleSliderWidth:960,autoScaleSliderHeight:750,slidesSpacing:0,imageScaleMode:'fill',imageScalePadding:0,arrowsNav:!1,globalCaption:!0,loopRewind:!0,keyboardNavEnabled:!0});
        colorsCount = 4;
        $('.rsGCaption').addClass('color' + Math.floor(Math.random() * colorsCount));
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your answer. The Royal slider is however being loaded via a plugin, so I'm not sure I can move that? Is there a way to execute a similar random hex script on just this part of the site, as it doesn't need to directly link to the other instances of colour-array?

Comment: Try putting the coloring code in this instead: 

`$( window ).load(function() {   })`

It's a little hacky, but it will ensure that that code executes after anything in `$( document ).ready(function() {   })`

Comment: That, or you could put your custom javascript at the bottom of the page, below the plugins, instead of in the head.  That will queue that code after the royalSlider code.

Comment: For some reason the js won't move to the bottom? Here is my register script: wp_register_script('custom', get_bloginfo('template_url'). '/js/custom.js', '1.0', true); with the in_footer attribute set to true? All of my scripts seem to load in <head> regardless of if this is set to true or false?

Comment: Try just adding the script tag to the footer manually like this: http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_footer

Comment: No it does not work even in the footer. I think I need to find a better solution all round for this random hex approach, do you have any ideas? I want to simply apply the class .colour-array to any element on the site and for it to load a random colour from 4 hex options. I'm finding my current solution to be limiting?

Comment: I can't think of a simpler solution that what you've come up with.  The simplest solution would be to edit the plugin with the code I provided in my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64805/discussion-between-casey-rule-and-dungey140).