# Assigning the same random colour to multiple divs on pageload

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want the background of the icon to randomize as the same colour as the text. You can see that there are four colour choices to pick from, so it's not exactly random, but randomized between the four choices.

http://chloesilver.ca/random.html

This is what I have so far:

### HTML:

```
<div class="monobg">
    <img src="http://chloesilver.ca/mono1.png" alt="mono1" />
</div>
```

### CSS:

```
.monobg  {
    background-color: red;
    padding:10px;
    width:60px;
}
```

### JS:

```
function random_imglink(){
    var myimages=new Array();
    //specify random images below. You can have as many as you wish
    myimages[1]="This is text1.";
    myimages[2]="This is text2.";
    myimages[3]="This is text3.";
    myimages[4]="This is text4.";
    myimages[5]="This is text5.";
    myimages[6]="This is text6.";

    var ry=Math.floor(Math.random()*myimages.length);
    if (ry==0)
        ry=1;
    document.write('<p>'+myimages[ry]+'</p>');
}
document.addEventHandler("ready", function() {
    random_imglink();
    var bgcolorlist = new Array("silver", "#BAF3C3", "#c3baf3", "red");
    document.body.style.color=bgcolorlist[Math.floor(Math.random()*bgcolorlist.length)];
});
```

I think the below link might be an answer but I can't seem to make sense of it:
[Random Hex colour from an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26237976/random-hex-colour-from-an-array)

Comment: You must know copy / paste isn't the right way to learn....If you are already changing the color of some text and you understand the code that do the action won't be a problem apply the same on the icon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this:

### HTML:

```
<div class="monobg">
    <img src="http://chloesilver.ca/mono1.png" />
</div>
<p>Some text</p>
```

### CSS:

```
.blue {
    color: blue;
}
.monobg {
    background-color: red;
    padding:10px;
    width:60px;
}
.blue .monobg {
    background: blue;
}
.red {
    color: red;
}
.red .monobg {
    background: red;
}
.green {
    color: green;
}
.green .monobg {
    background: green;
}
```

### Pure JS:

```
function setColor() {
    var colors = [" red", " green", " blue"],
        css = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
    document.querySelector("body").className = document.querySelector("body").className + css;
}
window.addEventListener("load", setColor);
```

Pure JS [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Marventus/cx3e7t33/) for reference.

### jQuery:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var colors = ["red", "green", "blue"],
            css = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
        $("body").addClass(css);
    });
});
```

jQuery [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Marventus/ts7m997p/) for reference.

### Explanation:

You define different css classes in your style sheet (one per color), and then you create a JS array containing each one of those css classes as values, and you assign only one of them randomly to the `body` element on `document.ready`.

Answer (score 0):

You have quite a few issues with your code here, let's go over them.

1.) Never create a javascript array like this `new Array("silver", "#BAF3C3", "#c3baf3", "red")`. It's overly verbose and provides no benefit. Use array literal syntax, like this: `["silver", "#BAF3C3", "#c3baf3", "red"]`

2.) The functionality is pretty trivial with a single added variable:

```
function randomTextAndIconColor(){
    var color = bgcolorlist[Math.floor(Math.random()*bgcolorlist.length)];
    document.querySelector('.monobg').style.backgroundColor = color;
    document.querySelector('body').style.color = color;
}
```